# publish sonar results to tfs build with .net core sonar scanner

Tags: c#, tfs, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have sonar scanner for .net core running in a Docker container:

Here is how I install the scanner in my docker container (DockerFile and howTo):

```
ENV SONAR_SCANNER_MSBUILD_VERSION 4.3.1.1372
RUN apt-get install -y unzip \
    && wget https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-msbuild/releases/download/$SONAR_SCANNER_MSBUILD_VERSION/sonar-scanner-msbuild-$SONAR_SCANNER_MSBUILD_VERSION-netcoreapp2.0.zip \
    && unzip sonar-scanner-msbuild-$SONAR_SCANNER_MSBUILD_VERSION-netcoreapp2.0.zip -d /sonar-scanner \
    && rm sonar-scanner-msbuild-$SONAR_SCANNER_MSBUILD_VERSION-netcoreapp2.0.zip \
    && chmod +x -R /sonar-scanner
```

This is how I scan the projects:

```
dotnet /sonar-scanner/SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll begin /k:sonarProjectKey /d:sonar.host.url="<SonarQubeServerUrl:Port>" /d:sonar.login="<SonarQubeServerToken>"
dotnet build
dotnet /sonar-scanner/SonarScanner.MSBuild.dll end  /d:sonar.login="<SonarQubeServerToken>"
```

How can I now publish the results from the sonar analyze back to the TFS build?

How can I break the build if the quality gate is red?

Comment: No third party sources allowed here.

Comment: fixed this comment and removed the link to github

Comment: Changed my rating after your update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to analyze projects with VSTS/TFS is with our extension:
https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Extension+for+VSTS-TFS

It will automatically publish results back to the TFS builds, but it is not possible to break the build when the Quality Gate is red. It used to allow breaking builds, but the feature was removed from version 4.0.

Please, read the article for detailed information.

Comment: thanks for the answer but I can not use the extension as we use an older TFS version and building under ubuntu. is there a command to publish the results?

Comment: There is nothing built-in as far as I know.